# openssl s_client -connect errorno=111

Tags: iptables, ssl, openssl

Hi I got problem with openssl connection. I have java application which connects from server1 to server2 I made clone of server2 and upgraded it from Debian 9.7 to Debian11. The connection to oldserver2 is working properly:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect oldserver2:143
CONNECTED(00000003)
140273164910656:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1707916719
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

But connection to new server2 have problem:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect newserver2:143
140319971628352:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140319971628352:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111
```

I can't find anything relevant about this on the internet. I am pretty sure on srever2 port 143 is opened

telnet is working properly towards newserver2

$ telnet server2 143
Also there are entries in iptables so i think I am sure port 143 is opened

Answer (score 0):

> The connection to oldserver2 is working properly:

It does not. It clearly throws an error and also the `Cipher : 0000` is an indicator that the TLS handshake failed. The only thing which was successful was the TCP connect, but not the TLS handshake.

> ```
> 140273164910656:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:252:
> ...
>     Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>     Cipher    : 0000
> ```

This error is kind of expected since you connect to port 143, which is reserved for IMAP. Traffic on this port is expected to start in plain and then get upgraded to TLS with an explicit STARTTLS command. This can also be done with adding `-starttls imap` to `openssl s_client`.

With the other server instead the TCP handshake already fails, since the connections gets refused:

> ```
> 140319971628352:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
> ```

There might be several reasons for this: wrong choice of server, server not running, server not properly configured, firewall in between ...

> telnet is working properly towards newserver2

Your comment on this answer shows clearly that telnet to the newserver2 fails, exactly the same as openssl s_client fails. So either the IMAP server is not running, not properly configured to use port 143, not configured to listen on external address, some firewall rules on the host, some firewall in between ... Too much options here and too much unknown about your configuration and environment.

Comment: General problem is more complicated. But on this point i am desperate in search for any hint to solve it.
`telnet oldserver2 143
Trying 10.1.1.12...
Connected to 10.1.1.12.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Welcome to Finanse mail.
^
* BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.

* BYE Too many invalid IMAP commands.
Connection closed by foreign host.
~$ telnet newserver2 143
Trying newserver2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
`

Comment: @Yawa86: what you show contradicts what you wrote in your question. The telnet command shows exactly the same problem as the s_client: Connection refused. So telnet is not successful as you've claimed.

Comment: ok thank You. So i need to start from the scratch.  This problem will put me in the grave.